# Loading WebView prevents other views from being loaded in the layout

Tags: android, layout, webview, load, render

I am trying to have a layout where there are a WebView and other views such as TextView.

From the code below, I am expecting the WebView to show up on the first 300dp in height and the TextView to show up at the bottom of the screen with the text 'Test Text'

Right now, when the code to load a url into a WebView is run (with the code snippet below), the WebView successfully loads the url, **however**, other views are ignored and not loaded.

Can someone please help me to load WebView and other views on the same screen?

I tried switching between:

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.temp_web_view);
```

and

```
WebView webView = findViewById(this);
```

Also,

```
setContentView(webView);
```

and

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_profiling_result);
```

but no luck so far..

*SomeActivity.java*

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profiling_result);

    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.temp_web_view);

    // must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    if (webView.getParent() != null) {
        ((ViewGroup)webView.getParent()).removeView(webView);
    }

    setContentView(webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String WEB_URL = "https://www.google.ca/";
    webView.loadUrl(WEB_URL);
}
```

*activity_profiling_result.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/temp_web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/temp_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Test Text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this

```
setContentView(webView);
// must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
if (webView.getParent() != null) {
    // this will remove the webView from the customise layout
    ((ViewGroup)webView.getParent()).removeView(webView);
}
```

because it will replace the whole layout with `webView` instance.

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_profiling_result);

Attach and display a customise layout (your webView or textview etc)

> setContentView(webView);

Attach and display webView instance

[**setContentView**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View))

> `Set the activity content to an explicit view. This view is placed
>   directly into the activity's view hierarchy`. It can itself be a
>   complex view hierarchy. When calling this method, the layout
>   parameters of the specified view are ignored. `Both the width and the`
>   `height of the view are set by default to MATCH_PARENT.` To use your own
>   layout parameters, invoke setContentView(android.view.View,
>   android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams) instead.

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profiling_result);

    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.temp_web_view);

    // must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    //if (webView.getParent() != null) {
        //((ViewGroup)webView.getParent()).removeView(webView);
    //}

    //setContentView(webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    String WEB_URL = "https://www.google.ca/";
    webView.loadUrl(WEB_URL);
}
```

Comment: setContentView(webView); does replace the whole layout with webView instance. However, when I put setContentView(R.layout.activity_profiling_result); it doesn't load anything. It's just a blank page after that line..

Comment: why you are doing this `(webView.getParent() != null)`? with this `((ViewGroup)webView.getParent()).removeView(webView);` you are removing the webView from the current layout so remove this as well

Comment: because I got the following error without it:
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
I removed the entire 'setContentView()' line and it's working as I wanted now.

Comment: Google told me to use 'setContentView()' in the example, and I used it and I was getting that error.. It's working fine without it.. Thanks.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView

Comment: Could you please take a look at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490283/only-viewpager-in-fragment-doesnt-slide-up-from-the-bottom-of-the-screen
as well? I posted this yesterday but no answers and no luck so far :(

Answer (score 1):

remove these codes it'll work as you expect

> if (webView.getParent() != null) {
>           ((ViewGroup)webView.getParent()).removeView(webView);
>       }
>       setContentView(webView);

your final code should be:

> @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.activity_profiling_result);
>       WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.temp_web_view);
>       webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
>       String WEB_URL = "https://www.google.ca/";
>       webView.loadUrl(WEB_URL); }

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly without setContentView(). I used it because it seemed like it was necessary according to:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView
Thanks!